# Symfony dump assets twice now app doesn't find css

Tags: php, css, symfony

I am new to Symfony and one form was messed up on my website so I decided to backup all the CSS files in web/css/compiled and I did

```
php app/console assets:install --symlink web --env=prod
php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod
```

which created other files on it...

When I open my website it doesn't load the new CSS files (eg: `all.css`) , when I inspect it loads the old one (eg : `all_all.css`)

I clear these cache

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod (and dev)
```

but it still doesn't load the right files

what can I do to make Symfony look for the new CSS files that were dumped?

Here is the head part of base.html.twig :

```
<head>
    <title>
        {%- block meta_title -%}
            {{ app.request.requestUri|slice(4)|replace({'/': " > ", '-': " ", '_': " "})|ucwords ~ " - " ~ cocorico_site_name }}
        {%- endblock -%}
    </title>
    <meta name="description" content="{%- block meta_description -%}{{ cocorico_short_description }}{%- endblock -%}">

    {%- block open_graph_data -%}{%- endblock -%}

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- set the viewport width and initial-scale on mobile devices -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!-- include the Open and Raleway Sans google font -->
    <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,300italic,400italic,600,700,600italic,700italic,800,800italic'
          rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!-- include the Raleway google font -->
    <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,100,200,300,500,600,700,800,900' rel='stylesheet'
          type='text/css'>

    <!-- include HTML5 IE enabling script and stylesheet for IE -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <link type="text/css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/ie.css') }}">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/vendor/ie.js') }}"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ asset('favicon.ico') }}">

    {% block stylesheets %}
        {% stylesheets
        'css/all.css'
        'css/all-override.css'
        'css/vendor/bootstrap-multiselect.css'
        'css/vendor/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css'

        filter='cssrewrite, ?minifycsscompressor' output='css/compiled/all.css' %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/css" media="all">
        {% endstylesheets %}
    {% endblock %}

    {# Safely using .ready() before including jQuery #}
    <script>
        (function (w, d, u) {
            w.readyQ = [];
            w.bindReadyQ = [];
            function p(x, y) {
                if (x == "ready") {
                    w.bindReadyQ.push(y);
                } else {
                    w.readyQ.push(x);
                }
            }
            var a = {ready: p, bind: p};
            w.$ = w.jQuery = function (f) {
                if (f === d || f === u) {
                    return a
                } else {
                    p(f)
                }
            }
        })(window, document);
    </script>

    {% include '@CocoricoCore/Frontend/Common/js/_google_analytics_js.html.twig' only %}

    {#Rich snippets used by search engines like google  #}
    {%- block markup_jsonld -%}
        {% include '@CocoricoSeo/Frontend/Common/_markup.jsonld.twig' ignore missing only %}
    {%- endblock -%}
</head>
```

Thank you

Comment: How do you store your assets (directly in web, under app/Resources or your bundle, e.g. src/AppBundle/Resources)? How do you load the assets in your template, e.g. what does your `<head />` section in your base.html.twig?

Comment: Hello, I think they are directly in web . Actually I use https://github.com/Cocolabs-SAS/cocorico so it's already pre made . I don't really know where things are. but all the css are under web/css

Comment: there is a folder web/assets so I think thats it they are in web directly ...thank you

Comment: Ok, more questions... You are compiling the assets for the `prod` env. Are you running your Symfony as prod app as well or in `dev`? You can usually tell by the profiler toolbar on the bottom of every page (if it's there you are in dev, if not in prod).

Comment: hello I'm in prod . Actually I followed a few steps in another thread (can't find the link again) it was saying to put in config.yml assetics : filters:
        cssrewrite:
           apply_to: "\.css$" then rm -rf app/cache then dump again; and it worked but my css is even worse ! i guess i need another thread for the css part! thank you